# Typesetting problems in Matlab figures with large fonts

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, typesetting

I'm preparing a simple Matlab figure for a presentation.  As such, I need the font size of the legend to be large.  This is causing some issues with typesetting of subscripts as seen below.

[image: Bad typesetting in subscripts]

I have issue with the large space between E and M and the subscripts zeros. I've overcome this in the past by saving the image and working with it in GIMP afterwards; however, I have several of these images and would like to do this in a more automated fashion.

Is there anyway to get better typesetting out of Matlab?  Particularly, can I force less whitespace before the subscripts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually cannot reproduce the problem.  Here is code that I would use to create that legend:

```
figure;
plot(randn(10,4))
h = legend(...
    'Approximate Model solution M_0 = 1e5', ...
    'Full Model solution M_0 = 1e5', ...
    'Approximate Model solution E_0 = 1e5', ...
    'Full Model solution E_0 = 1e5');
```

For me, it renders without the extra spacing you show in your picture.

---

If you really need to make fine adjustments to the spacing, you can try using Latex to add some negative horizontal space, like so:

For a title:

```
title('abc\hspace{-1pt}efg','interpreter','latex')
```

For a legend:

```
warning off MATLAB:tex              %Disable a warning cause by the next line ... 
h = legend('abc\hspace{-1pt}efg');  %... there may be a cleaner way 
set(h,'interpreter','latex');
```

Comment: When I change the interpreter to latex on the legend, I get several warnings `Warning: Unable to interpret LaTeX string` and the text is not rendered.  I assume I need to do something else, but I've not been able to deduce how to proceed.